# What's so special about `hal.dll+12a3b`?

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit, bsod

I have a BSOD/STOP 0x124 problem that keeps haunting me for a very very long time: It always happens at address [hal.dll+12a3b](http://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/252349-random-bsods-hal-dll-12a3b-ntoskrnl-exe-18cb03-irql-0x124.html).

In my searches for an explanation/solution, I found suggestions that this crash may be a result of either overclocking or [bad RAM](http://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/216251-bsod-while-gaming-only-hal-dll-12a3b-0x124.html#post1814605).

Since I don't overclock my system, bad RAM could have been a possibility but... my system **never crashes when running Ubuntu** (under much more demanding memory conditions: multiple VMWare VMs running simultaneously, including Windows 7 64-bit VMs).

So, other than a bug in Windows 7, I have no other explanation for the phenomenon but I am still curious:

What's there in that special [hal.dll+12a3b](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&q=%22hal.dll+12a3b%22&oq=%22hal.dll+12a3b%22&gs_l=hp.3..0.1464.2548.0.2884.3.3.0.0.0.0.259.518.1j1j1.3.0...0.0...1c.1.14.psy-ab.qF-3kj3uCXo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47008514,d.dmg&fp=d068b7ffa816e432&biw=1078&bih=757) address?

Comment: HAL - Hardware Abstraction Layer. Also look into bad or seriously out of date drivers. It's probably the main difference between the two OS's in this instance.

Comment: upload the dmp fiels so that we can look at them with Windbg.

Comment: Bug Check 0x124 is [WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Please post at least parameters of bugchecks you got (either recorded from bluescreens, or found in the System event log). MCi values can be analyzed, e.g., according to [this guide](http://www.sevenforums.com/crash-lockup-debug-how/35349-stop-0x124-what-means-what-try.html). You can also check for a BIOS update (I have seen unexplainable MCEs on a server which had gone away after updating the BIOS).

Comment: any news? have you uploaded the dumps?